# Capacitance of bodies with different charge

Tags: capacitance

How does one calculate the capacitance of two bodies *with different charges*? I was looking at coefficients of potential, but they don't seem helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capacitor with different charges on each plate](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101116/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does one calculate the capacitance of two bodies with different
>   charges?

To be clear, *capacitance doesn't depend on the amount of charge*; the capacitance is determined by the geometry of the bodies.

If you have two conductors, there are actually *three* capacitances to consider, the [*self-capacitance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Self-capacitance) of each and *mutual capacitance* of the two conductors.

> In electrical circuits, **the term capacitance is usually a shorthand
>   for the mutual capacitance between two adjacent conductors**, such as
>   the two plates of a capacitor. However, for an isolated conductor
>   there also exists a property called self-capacitance, which is the
>   amount of electrical charge that must be added to an isolated
>   conductor to raise its electrical potential by one unit (i.e. one
>   volt, in most measurement systems).[20] The reference point for this
>   potential is a theoretical hollow conducting sphere, of infinite
>   radius, centered on the conductor.

Let $Q_1$ be the charge on conductor 1 and $Q_2$ the charge on conductor 2.

Further let $C_1$ be the self-capacitance of conductor 1, $C_2$ the self-capacitance of conductor 2, and $C_{12}$ the mutual capacitance.

We can then write:

$$Q_1 = C_1 V_1 + C_{12}(V_1 - V_2)$$

$$Q_2 = C_2 V_2 + C_{12}(V_2 - V_1)$$

For an *intentional* capacitor, the self-capacitance of the conductors is insignificant, i.e., the mutual capacitance *dwarfs* the self-capacitance of the conductors and we speak of **the** capacitance of the capacitor which is understood to be the mutual capacitance.

Comment: Is there a proof of correctness of coefficients of potential somewhere? Also, why did you take the difference of the potentials?

Comment: @Anthony, because the voltage between (or across) the two conductors is precisely the potential *difference*:  $V_{12} = V_1 - V_2$.

Comment: Finally I understand. God bless you