# Why do both plates of a capacitor have the same charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

How do we know that both plates of a capacitor have the same charge?

You could argue conservation of charge, but I don't see how conservation of charge implies the charge on both plates is the same.

Say you have a charge of +q on one plate and -m on the other. +q doesn't equal -m.  How do we know that the difference of charge doesn't end up on the terminals? Isn't that possible? Wouldn't conservation of charge not be violated if the charges on both plates are not equal, but the difference in charges ends up as surface charge in the wire or some other place in the circuit?

Comment: related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101116/capacitor-with-different-charges-on-each-plate/101205#101205

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason the sides have to be equal, but if they aren't, the capacitor obviously has a net electric charge. Moreover, the electric field lines emanating from the capacitor have to go somewhere, such that the whole capacitor is also one half of a larger capacitor. In a circuit model, you would simply represent this as two or more separate capacitors, each individually balanced with zero net charge.

If the net charge of the entire circuit is nonzero, then you have to add a capacitor with a terminal going "nowhere," to a node representing the outside world. The capacitance of this depends on environmental conditions, i.e. the dielectric constant of air, and the shape of the electric field (particularly the surface area of the exposed metal).

Answer (score -1):

> How do we know that both plates of a capacitor have the same charge?

In the context of ideal circuit theory, KCL (based on conservation of electric charge) holds.

For a capacitor connected to an external *circuit*, KCL demands that the current *into* one terminal equals the current *out of* the other terminal.  This implies that the charge on each plate is equal and opposite.

Now, it is certainly possible to *place* unequal charge on the plates of a capacitor and I've seen this done in an undergrad physics lab.  *But it wasn't in a circuit context*.

Context is *crucial*.  Attempting to apply results outside of the context (assumptions) upon which they're based is an elementary (though, unfortunately, common) error.

---

Addendum to address a comment by @Physiks lover:

> user41086's point is a good one. KCL is concerned about currents at a
>   single node, not at multiple nodes.

It isn't a good point because the statement that KCL isn't concerned about current at multiple nodes isn't true.  One can draw a surface enclosing two or more nodes and KCL holds for the supernode.

Supernodes are most commonly used to enclose a floating voltage source in order to apply node voltage analysis.

[image]

But supernodes are more general than that.  For example, see these [MIT EE course notes on nodal analysis.](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/nodal_mesh_methd.pdf)

> "The part of the circuit enclosed by the dotted ellipse is called a
>   supernode. **Kirchhoff’s current law may be applied to a supernode in
>   the same way that it is applied to any other regular node.** This is
>   not surprising considering that KCL describes charge conservation
>   which holds in the case of the supernode as it does in the case of a
>   regular node."

Thus *we can enclose the entire capacitor with a supernode and apply KCL*.  In this *ideal* circuit context (which includes a number of assumptions that only approximate reality), the stipulation that the charge on each plate is equal and opposite is valid.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand. 1) I haven't really studied KCL but what I understood from a quick Google search is that the current going into a node is equivalent to the current coming out. How can the capacitor be considered a node? The two terminals/plates of the capacitor are not connected! 2) During the transient state of the circuit, a steady current isn't established, so how can KCL be valid? 3) What's an external circuit?

Comment: @user41086, I *have* studied (and taught) KCL.  (1) we can "enclose" the capacitor within a "supernode" (2) KCL is a *good* approximation (otherwise, circuit simulator software such as SPICE that rely on it wouldn't be used as extensively and with such success as it is) which is exact in the steady state limit (3) the circuit elements attached to the capacitor.

Comment: What's a supernode? And could you explain why KCL is a good approximation during the transient state? Your answer is really over my head, I was hoping I would be able to understand this without having to learn more stuff because this concept seems pretty elementary.

Comment: @user41086, this is elementary EE "stuff".  If it's over your head, the proper conclusion to draw is that you've some more homework to do; "hoping to understand" without "learning more stuff" is no different than "hoping for success without having earned it".  I find that repugnant.  For me, "learning more stuff" is the entire point of "hoping for understanding".

Comment: Fine. Could you address my questions in my last comment?

Comment: @user41086, not a chance.

Comment: Why not? They're valid questions...

Comment: @user41086, *because I see no profit in it*.

Comment: Seriously? What "profit" do you see in answering my question in the first place then? It seems kinda pointless to answer a question, and then refuse to clarify points I'm confused about. It doesn't really help me, and it wastes your time...

Comment: @user41086, what debt do I owe you and how did I earn it?

Comment: You don't owe me anything. You chose to answer my question, which I appreciate, but you choosing not to clarify my questions makes your answer useless to me. You didn't have to help me, but if your going to choose to put effort into answering my question, you might as well address my concerns, because as it stands, your answer doesn't help me making the effort you put into answering the question completely pointless.

Comment: @user41086, indeed I did put effort into answering your question and I expected a return on that effort.  You evidently find it of little value and are unwilling to provide anything in return.  What you seem to want is 'knowledge' without the effort; understanding without "learning more stuff".  That's not the 'profit' I seek.

Comment: I never said I find it of little value. I just find it confusing because I don't know enough to understand it. I'd be glad to put in effort to understand your question, but I'm not willing to learn an enormous amount of new stuff to understand an elementary concept. The concepts in your answer might be elementary to you, but their certainly not to me. Just a guess, but are you an objectivist?

Comment: user41086's point is a good one. KCL is concerned about currents at a single node, not at multiple nodes.

Comment: @Physikslover, I've amended my answer to address your concern.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Out of curiosity, are an objectivist? It would explain a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Capacitor needs to be connected to some dc source for completely charging it.When you connect it to the DC SOURCE, the current will start to flow such that charges on both surface is increasing with opposite polarities. To obey KCL, charges on both plates should must be same. WHICH IS(That is KCL) TRUE HERE DUE TO AMPERE'S Modified Circuital law which includes **displacement current**.

If Suppose you just bring charged plate near another neutral plate then charge of opposite polarity is gathering on near side of neutral plate(Still neutral).Then you just connect other side of neutral plate to earth to get overall negative charge (which may not be equal of another positive charged plate) and earth accepts the positive charge from plate which is now negatively charged and doesn't show much change in potential due to high capacitance of 711 microfarad.So overall charge is still conserved.

Comment: Will someone tell me of downvote Reason so I can Help.

Comment: It is true that a capacitor connected to a perfect DC source will be charged exactly to its DC voltage. However, the act of connecting the capacitor to the DC source adds an AC component, and in a completely DC model a capacitor is only an open circuit. Also, appealing to KCL is begging the question. "Because this law says so" is not a good reason, when the premise of the question (which is valid) is that the condition of unequal charge is physically possible.

Comment: We are considering only ideal circuit and I don't go in more details. Further Capacitor connected in ideal dc circuit (no ac) first should must not be perfect almost open circuit.And in closed circuit with capacitor and battery source to conserve charge(BECAUSE IT HAPPENS IN NATURE AND NEVER GONE WRONG) Capacitor plates must be charged with same charge.If I am Wrong Please explain me in detail