# Will the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor be different if the overall charge on it is not neutral?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

If we have two metal plates of surface area A placed at a small distance d from each other such that one plate has a +Q charge while the other plate is overall neutral, then will the capacitance of this system differ from the general situation where both plates are overall neutral?[image]

Comment: One way of thinking may be: the capacitance of a two plates capacitor is affected by the charge distribution of the plates?

Comment: I tried thinking it with the electric field due to these charged surfaces but by doing that I don't think it will affect the electric field inside the plates and hence capacitance should remain same as that in general case.

Comment: The formula for capacitance is $C=\frac {A\epsilon_0}{d}$. This gives a hint as to what factors affect the capacitance.

Comment: From this can it be concluded that capacitance doesn't change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capacitor with different charges on each plate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101116)

Comment: Thanks, I got it now :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capacitor with different charges on each plate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101116/capacitor-with-different-charges-on-each-plate)